# Error in startup script: invalid command name "ttk::progressbar"

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I am trying to use a tkk progress bar but its failing with following message.
Do i need to install a separate package for TKK ?
I am using tcl version 8.6.

Following is my trail code.

```
#!/usr/bin/wish

package require Tk
pack [ttk::progressbar .p1 -orient horizontal -length 200 -mode indeterminate -value 90]
pack [ttk::progressbar .p2 -orient horizontal -length 200 -mode determinate -variable a -maximum 75 -value 20]
```

Comment: I'm not getting this error here running your snippet. Tk version is 8.6.4. It should work however, since it was introduced in 8.5.

Comment: Check that your code is using the version you think it is. Add this command to your script: `puts "Running using Tcl [package require Tcl] and Tk [package require Tk]"`

Comment: wish "script name" gives error.
while tclsh "script_name" works.
don't understand the difference b/w the invocation, plzz explain.